# Devops variable group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a situation where I have a variable group that will hold the credential (username/pwd) which will be used by my pipeline task.

I want to use one variable group for holding credentials for all environment and I want to add environment names(dev, test. etc) to all the variables so I can use it as a parameter to help the task distinguish which one to use. I do not want to create multiple variable groups for each environment.

My variable group name: CredentialsVariableGroup
Variables:
usernamedev
pwddev
usernametest
pwdtest
usernameuat
pwduat
usernameprod
pwdprod

Now in the yaml, I will pass environment name while calling this. Potential values for environment name - dev, test, prod:

```
parameters:
- name: environmentName
  type: string

// some other parameters, stages, variable groups, jobs

- task: Sometask
  displayName: Sometaskdisplayname
  inputs:
    username: '$(usernamedev)' 
    password: '$(pwddev)'
```

I want a way to make the environment name part to be used from parameter so this becomes dynamic and refers the right variable when deploying in the respective environment.

Edit:

Snap of my variable in Library (Pipeline)
[image]

My Yaml Pipeline

```
parameters:
- name: environmentName
  type: string

stages:
- stage: 
  dependsOn:  
  condition: 
  displayName: 
  variables:
  - group: Group1
  - group: Group2
  - group: 'MyVariableGroup'
  - template: vars.yaml
  - ${{ if ne(parameters[''], 'PROD') }}:
    - group: NonProdGroup

  - ${{ if eq(parameters[''], 'PROD') }}:
    - group: ProdGroup

  - group: Group3
  - group: Group4
 
  pool:
    name: Default
  jobs:
  - deployment: 
    displayName: 
    pool:
      name: Default
    environment: 
      name: ${{ parameters.paramname }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: current
              artifact: drop

            - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
              displayName: 'Deploy arm template'
              inputs:
                azureResourceManagerConnection: 
                subscriptionId: ''
                deploymentName: $()
                location: ''
                resourceGroupName: 
                csmFile: ''
                csmParametersFile: ''
                deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

  - job: DeployApiApp
    dependsOn: 
    displayName: 
    steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        displayName: 
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          downloadType: 'single'
          artifactName: 'drop'
          downloadPath: ''

      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 
        inputs:
          appType: webApp
          azureSubscription: ''
          appName: ''
          package: ''

  - job: DeployWebApp
    dependsOn: 
    displayName: 
    steps:
      - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
        displayName: 
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          downloadType: 'single'
          artifactName: 'drop'
          downloadPath: ''    

      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 
        inputs:
          appType: webApp
          azureSubscription: ''
          appName: ''
          package: ''

  - job: DeployDB
    dependsOn: 
    displayName: 
    steps:
      - download: current
        artifact: 

      - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
        displayName: 
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: ''
          ServerName: ''
          DatabaseName: ''
          SqlUserName: ''
          SqlPassword: $[variables['adminpwd${{ upper(parameters.environmentName) }}']] 
          deployType: 'DacpacTask'
          DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
          DacpacFile: ''
          AdditionalArguments: ''
          IpDetectionMethod: ''
          StartIpAddress: ''
          EndIpAddress: ''
          DeleteFirewallRule:
```

Comment: Please explain *why* you want to take this approach. Variable groups should be separated into one per environment. Otherwise, you run the risk of a dev deployment potentially using production credentials with disastrous consequences.

Comment: Daniel Mann: I do not think this list will have more variables may be one or two at max. And this is why I am looking to have just one variable group and differentiating using environment name. Let's say we go for one for all lower environment and one exclusively for Prod to address your concern. I am just trying to understand if this can be achieved the way I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @daniel-mann, you probably don't want to mix variables from different environments in the same variable group.

If you need to build your variable name dynamically, this syntax should work:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environmentName
  type: string

steps:
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "$(username${{parameters.environmentName}})"
```

Depending on how you organize your yaml files, runtime variable should work as well:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environmentName
  type: string

jobs:
- job: A
  variables:
  - group: my-variable-group-name
  - name: username
    value: $[variables['username${{parameters.environmentName}}']]
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Host "$(username)"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it failed with same error: I checked the azure-pipelines-expanded.yaml and saw the input is username: $[variables['usernameD']] (Consider Development environment). The one that worked fine username: '$(usernameD)'. Could it be how the format is coming in the way we tried. Just to add: I still have the - group: 'VariableGroup' in my yaml

Comment: Could you share you yaml file ? and names of the variable in the variable group ? Just tried on my side and it is working and resolving as $(usernamedev)

Comment: Done, added the complete yaml (cleaned up) and the snap of my variable from Azure devops in the question

Comment: Meanwhile I hardcoded the variable name from variable group '$(adminpwdD)' and this worked

Comment: so which approach did you try: `$(username${{parameters.environmentName}})` or `$[variables['username${{parameters.environmentName}}']]`?

Comment: using runtime variable, I tihnk you have to assign it to another variable, you cant use directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254043/discussion-between-lucky-and-thomas).

Comment: SqlPassword: '$(adminpwd${{upper(parameters.envName)}})' This worked for me, thank you Thomas!

Answer (score 0):

So first you will want to load the variable group . I think the best way to achieve this will also be to use a [variable template file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse) to store the base names you are looking for.

```
variables:
- group: variableGroupName
- template: variablesNames.yml
```

Then for the individual ones you'd reference the parameters like:

```
- task: Sometask
  displayName: Sometaskdisplayname
  inputs:
    username: ${{variables.username}}${{parameters.environmentName) 
    password: ${{variables.username}}${{parameters.environmentName)
```

You can confirm how this works by downloading the azure-pipeline-expanded.yml file after the run to see the templates fully expand. I would still recommend loading the variable group with the environment name. i.e. separate variable group for each environment. This is due to variable group security as well as pipeline variable scoping.

The separate variable template file is not needed; however, I have found it helps when scaling.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have a question in the approach you suggested: Lets say I created a yaml file to define my variables, then the value of the variables in my case (username and password) will be available in plain text. However, if I add in a variable group in pipeline I do not have to worry about it. Is my understanding correct? Please let me know.

Comment: In the scenario you are proposing the value 'username' and 'password' would be in the variable file. This would be the key not the value. The value would be retrieved in the variable group.  So when the pipeline expands it will look for `usernameDev` in the variable group that is loaded into the job's scope.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the explanation. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I tried it but got the following error: Unable to connect to target server ''. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.

Comment: I created a yaml file: variables:
  passwordVariableName: 'pwd' In my release yaml - group: 'GroupName'
  - template: variablesNames.yaml. And in the task password: ${{variables.passwordVariableName}}${{upper(parameters.environmentName)}}

Comment: Download the azure-pipeline-expanded.yml file and see what value it is concatenating/expanding to.

Comment: My sincere request to whoever marked it -1 is please comment to let us know the reason. I don't think it is not a helpful response. Sorry DreadedFrost. Can you please explain me further what you mean when you say download the yml file or let me know how to. I am at beginner level with this. Thanks!

Comment: Click on a pipeline that has completed and select the ellipse menu n the top right and select "Download Logs". This will download a zip and one of the files is the 'azure-pipelines-expanded.yml'. Here is a link to a more [detailed troubleshooting step](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-templates-tasks-and-jobs/ba-p/3712459).

Comment: Now that I look at this I am not sure if it will work as desired. [Something like this](https://blog.johnfolberth.com/securely-populating-azure-key-vault-via-azure-devops/) might be more accurate.

Comment: I will check the links and see if that helps my situation. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help and support DreadedFrost! I marked the answer helpful as I did not think it deserved a down vote.